# Bypass ~/.profile on remote login to a linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, .profile

Is there a way to bypass or prevent the execution of `~/.profile` when logging into a remote Linux server using either ssh or putty?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just edit the values in the file? (It's your profile, after all.)

Comment: This is usefull for instance if someone screwed up the .profile file and you don't have direct access to the system :)

Comment: That's exactly the situation I found myself in monkey_p

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For bash:

```bash
$ ssh hostname "bash --noprofile"
```

Comment: You'll also need the `-t` option, I think.

Comment: ssh -t hostname "bash --noprofile" .If -t wasn't there I was getting the error "standard in must be a tty".

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking to disable all login scripts, you can use the `--noprofile` flag to disable `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, etc. and `--norc` to disable `~/.bashrc` like so:

```bash
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 "bash --noprofile --norc"
```

Keep in mind you can also launch an alternative shell if one is available.  I've had to use this after messing up in `chsh`:

```csh
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 sh
```

This will most likely drop you to a blank shell (no prompt) so give it an `ls` to make sure it is working.

Answer (score 4):

If your target machine is in a bash shell:

```
user@host:/$ ssh hostname "bash --noprofile"
```

Alternatively, if there's another profile you wish to use

```
user@host:/$ ssh hostname "bash --noprofile; source ~/.other_profile"
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, running [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) with the `--noprofile` flag when you initiate the connection will work, although if you're using a different shell this may or may not be an option.

One alternative would be to have the profile script detect an SSH connection itself and behave accordingly.  Since SSH connections will normally set a number of environment variables, this can easily be checked.  Adding something like the following lines to the start of your profile should suffice:

```
if [ "$SSH_CONNECTION" != "" ]; then
  echo Logging in with ssh
  return
else
  echo Logging in with something that is not ssh
fi

# rest of your profile goes here
```

The `return` will skip the rest of the script if the `$SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable is set, which would normally be created whenever an SSH connection is initiated.  Otherwise the profile will be run like normal.

Note that this will only skip the affected profile script.  All other profile scripts (e.g.: `/etc/profile`) would still be processed unless you modify them similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try using a FTP program like WinSCP to delete the mistaken login file. This will discard it, but at least you should be able to login to the default shell

Comment: or perhaps just rename it.